# How would I return a field from xml in sql

Tags: sql-server

Here is my code:

```
(select top (1) (dbo.get_xml_value(xml_data,''))
from t_Order_Detail_Form_Data 
where t_Order_Detail_Form_Data.order_detail_id = t_Order_Detail.Order_Detail_ID) as DOM
```

And the field I want

```
<Showings_Since_Listed>25</Showings_Since_Listed>
```

I want to return the 25

I think I am on the right path but I am unsure.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there a problem with your code? Does it work or not, any errors? What is `dbo.get_xml_value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer to my issue
`(select top (1) (dbo.get_xml_value(xml_data,'/PS_FORM/MONTHLY_STATUS_REPORT/Offer_Amount'))`

the only way i can get it to work is by using the entire xpath, so much for security.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx

Comment: That is only good if you are using full xpath which I can not because of security.  I must use a function to call the field, that is why you see the get.xml above.  I just wanted to know how to declare that field in the above.